# Are Cognito refresh tokens "valid" JSON web tokens?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jwt, amazon-cognito

I have been trying to validate the "refresh token" returned by Amazon Cognito Identity Provider via their boto3 python client. I've been using the validator at https://jwt.io.

When I paste the refresh token into the "encoded" box, it returns a header:

```
{
  "cty": "JWT",
  "enc": "A256GCM",
  "alg": "RSA-OAEP"
}
```

but the tool also says "invalid signature" at the bottom.

I'm wondering if this is expected behavior? Are AWS Cognito refresh tokens not valid JWTs?

Comment: Have you pasted the signing credentials into jwt.io as well?

Comment: I've passed a secret block, base64 encoded and a signature (utf-8). Neither of these are valid in the debugger tool for decoding the refresh token, even when I select "secret base64 encoded" in the verify signature field.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, with this header it appears that the refresh token is a valid JWT.

https://jwt.io is not able to parse it because it is limited to signed JWT (JWS - [RFC7515](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7515)) and this one is an encrypted one (JWE - [RFC7516](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7516)).

Contrary to the JWS, the JWE is composed of 5 parts separated by dots. Its header can be parsed, but the payload is encrypted and cannot be read without the private or shared key.

According to the `cty` header, this token contains another JWT that is certainly a JWS. This nested token allows both of the two worlds: signed and encrypted claims.

Comment: Thanks for this info. Just to clarify: jwt.io is _not_ able to verify JWE tokens?

Comment: jwt.io is able to parse and verify the signed tokens (JWS), but it is not able to parse and decrypt encrypted tokens (JWE)